# How do I programmatically/automatically change the text formatting for the text of a Visio shape after I am done with the editing?

Tags: events, macros, visio

Here is what I want to achive:
 I want to use Visio to document a project. I have some Visio text boxes that contain code examples.
The code examples have comments in them. The comments are line comments (either the line begins with # or they are places at the end of the line beginning with #

What I need is to have Visio change the comments to another color automatically after I am done with the editing of that shape (a text square).

From what I read this can be achieved with the following:

-use "TheText" event and CALLTHIS("Function-name")

-the "Function-name" procedure should read the text of the shape and search for "#" on each line and turn the text on that line to let's say "grey" till the end of the line.

Could you please confirm me if I am on the right path with this?
I am a totally beginner with Visio and VBA. 
To test the above I used a Macro that should move the shape as soon as the editing is done

Sub Macro()

```
'Enable diagram services
Dim DiagramServices As Integer
DiagramServices = ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled
ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = visServiceVersion140

ActiveWindow.DeselectAll
ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(88), visSelect
Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Move 0.5, 0#


'Restore diagram services
ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = DiagramServices
```

End Sub

And "TheText" event cell had this =CALLTHIS("ThisDocument.Macro")

I expected the shape to move to right as soon as I was done with the editing but it did not happen
What am I doing wrong?

thanks a lot
P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sub, it's not very well programmed, but it should do the trick.

You need to add the code to the ThisDocument module in the VBA editor (press Alt+F11 to open it).

Actually, the TheText() event won't call the formatting function AFTER you're done with the text editing: It will be called time and again while modify the text (whenever you press a key, format or resize your text box), which would be quite inefficient.

I would use another event, like EvntDoubleClick() instead, or a user defined menu optionj, to call the changeColor sub.

```
  Sub changeColor(oShape As Visio.Shape)

     On Error GoTo Err_changeColor

     Dim iLength As Integer
     Dim iBeginOffset As Integer, iEndOffset As Integer
     Dim oShpChar As Visio.Characters

     Set oShpChar = oShape.Characters

     iLength = oShpChar.CharCount

     ' Main loop: We go through all the text selecting the adecuate portions to change
     Do
        ' Find the position of next # character
        iBeginOffset = InStr(oShpChar.Text, "#")
        If iBeginOffset = 0 Then Exit Do    ' # Not found -> end the loop

        ' Find the position of next LF to change color only until the end of the line
        iEndOffset = InStr(iBeginOffset, oShpChar.Text, vbLf)
        If iEndOffset = 0 Then iEndOffset = iLength - oShpChar.Begin      ' If not found, change everything

        ' Update the portion to change
        oShpChar.End = oShpChar.Begin + iEndOffset          ' We use the previous beginning position plus the offset
        oShpChar.Begin = oShpChar.Begin + iBeginOffset - 1  ' Idem. We want to change #'s color, too, thus the (-1)

        ' Change color of the selected text (between Begin and End) to green (9)
        oShpChar.CharProps(visCharacterColor) = 9

        oShpChar.Begin = oShpChar.Begin + 1    ' We don't want to find the same # again, so we undo the previous (-1)
        oShpChar.End = iLength                 ' We want to continue searching until the end

     Loop While (iEndOffset <> iLength)

  Exit_changeColor:

     If Not oShpChar Is Nothing Then Set oShpChar = Nothing
     Exit Sub

  Err_changeColor:

     MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error"
     Resume Exit_changeColor

  End Sub
```

Comment: Guys where do I add the code? This is driving me crazy. this is what I did: TheText=("ThisDocument.changeColor") and I pasted your code in the ThisDocument section of the code. Nothing happens when I edit the text in that box. Question: if I use TheText is the code going to be executed every time I type a letter or just at the end of the editing?

Comment: Hmm I was trying that in a document that I was editing. Not sure what went wrong there but when I moved the code to a fresh new empty document  it worked

Comment: Thanks for the above solution. I am now testing the code within the above loop. How do I use a hex color code in the above? I need to use White Darker 35% which I don't think it is in the pallette used for visCharacterColor.  The other thing I wanted to mention is that the loop in your code does not take into consideration that while you type new characters are added to the shape text and for that reason iLenght should be measured with each iteration. I will work on that by myself

Comment: It seems that you where able to figure out where to write the code. For colors take a look at the RGB or HSL functions. 
"iLenght should be measured with each iteration..." No, iLenght is meassured each time the macro is called. When you insert a character, a new call to the macro is done. This is very inefficient, and that's why I suggested you to use the DoubleClick event instead, or, still better, a user defined menu: "Format Text".

Comment: You add user defined menus within the "Actions" section in the Page's or Shape's ShapeSheet.

Comment: HI Clon thanks for the suggestions. For the color thing I solved that by editing the color pallette to be what I wanted and I am OK

Comment: as far as the code efficiency goes I am OK with this solution, the delay  is almost imperceptible. However I will consider your suggestion for the next step when I want the text box to format code keyword automatically :-) That will be challenging and it will probably have to be done by the end of editing once in one pass for the entire text

Comment: Hmm the code posted above is fine but in some situations it seems that while I am editing the text Visio keeps looping TheText event. I am not sure why. I could see that the timeglass was spinning (Visio was doing something) and it would not end without me pressing control+break. Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: As I already said, I wouldn't use the TheText() event to do something with the text. It seems that somehow the code is firing the event and this is resulting in an endless loop.

Comment: I solved the problem by exposing exposing shape events to VBA and I worked with that. Please see here: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688868/how-do-i-use-textchanged-event-in-vba-visio) Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

The CALLTHIS shapesheet function expects that you'll have a sub/function with the name matching the first argument, obviously with dots separating the module and routine names.  The second argument is the VBA project name, which is optional.

CALLTHIS also expects that your routine will have its first argument be the Visio.Shape that is firing the event, so your Sub Macro() should actually be Sub Macro(ShpObj as Visio.Shape).  I think after you do that, the event should work.