# How do I use TextChanged event in VBA visio?

Tags: vba, events, visio, textchanged

This is related to this question
[How do I programmatically/automatically change the text formatting for the text of a Visio shape after I am done with the editing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614724/how-do-i-programmatically-automatically-change-the-text-formatting-for-the-text)

There I tried to use some code that would be executed when the text of a shape is edited
For some reasons, as described there, in some situations which I could not isolate the code is executed endlessly.
That is probably because the script calls itself in a loop. The code is supposed to be executed every time the text of the shape is edited BUT the code itself changes the color of the text. I guess that would count as a new text change and so on.

I am thinking about using the event called TextChanged. According with the documentation this should execute the code when the user finished the editing
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff768749.aspx

I could not find a example of using such event in VBA and here is where I need your help
thanks in advance
Uni

This is how I tested:
I used CallThis('ThisDocument.warning") to call the procedure below from "TheText" event of that shape (available via the shapesheet)

Sub warning(oShape As Visio.Shape)
MsgBox ("Text edited")
End Sub

This gets executed like three times if I star editing the text of a shape and I press the space key (adding a space to the existing text)

Comment: OK this is as far as I could get: I have to declare a shape object WithEvents to expose the events of that object. Now I need help to understand how I can call that _TextChanged procedure when a shape's text changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is how you do it:

Open the Code editor
In the Project explorer select  "ThisDocument"
Next in the ObjectWindow select Document
Then in the Method dropdown box select ShapeExitedTextEdit
You will see a skeleton procedure like below

Private Sub Document_ShapeExitedTextEdit(ByVal oShape As IVShape)

End Sub

There is where you add the code that you want to be executed every time when the editing if finished